# How to access (via javascript) to the current theme's palette colors in angular material?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

In [`angular-material`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest), we can define color palettes in an angular `config` block the folowing way:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('pink')
    .accentPalette('orange');
});
```

Its pretty great...

**But**

I can't find a way to handle the current color value of given palette, simply for using the same colors on elements, custom or not, that don't match the list of natively supported elements.

The elements that support theming are :

- md-button
- md-checkbox
- md-progress-circular
- md-progress-linear
- md-radio-button
- md-slider
- md-switch
- md-tabs
- md-text-float
- md-toolbar

> refs https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/02_declarative_syntax

Maybe a little more, but sure, custom elements are not supported.

Thus, if I create a custom `DOM` element, or nested elements (anyway), **how can I apply the current `700` value of the `warn` palette of the current `default` theme ?**

I didn't found anything in the API.

I search something like a `service` exposing one or more method(s) usable like following, for example:

```
$mdTheme.getTheme('default');
```

This method, for example, should return an object filled by all palettes filled in this theme.

### EDIT : an example of usage

> this example is not *beautiful* code design, but it is to be simple

Then, I will be able to expose it on scope and use it in other (custom or native) directives:

```
// controller:
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$mdTheme){

  var primary500 = $mdTheme.getTheme('default').getPalette('primary').getHue('500');

  $scope.customStyleBorderPrimary = {
    'border-bottom': 'solid 2px ' + primary500
  };

}
```

and then

```
<!-- in view -->
<h4 ng-style="customStyleBorderPrimary" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  My h4 title with primary border-bottom
</h4>
```

Comment: you want to apply material's default palettes to your custom directives ?

Comment: For example, yes. Or being able to apply it in style attribute of custom elements : `<span ng-style="{'border-bottom':'solid 2px '+palettePrimary500">` or something else.

Comment: You can write your own css class with color palettes from https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I just created a set of useful directives wrapped in an angularjs module (`swapMdPaint`) packaged in a bower package (`swap-md-paint`).**

### Fork, documentation and downloads

> https://github.com/rbecheras/swap-md-paint

### Install

You can install it as follow:

```
bower install swap-md-paint --save
```

or manually:

> http://bower.io/search/?q=swap-md-paint

or via git clone

```
git clone https://github.com/sirap-group/swap-md-paint.git public/lib/swap-md-paint
cd public/lib/swap-md-paint
git checkout v0.4.0
```

### Import

Then you need to import it in your application:

First, append `public/lib/swap-md-paint/swap-md-paint.min.js` in your `body` tag in `index.html`

And register `swapMdPaint` as a module dependency of your application.

### API

Now you can use it as follow:

You can use the default theme's `accent` color

```
<div swap-md-paint-fg="accent">Default Themes Accent Color</div>
```

Or the default themes `primary` palette `hue-1` and so on.

```
<div swap-md-paint-fg="hue-1">Default Themes Primary Palette Hue-1</div>
```

You can specify `theme([default])` intent palette ( `[primary], accent, warn, background` ) and hue ( `[default] hue-1, hue-2, hue-3`)

> [ ] => the default if you enter nothing.

- `swap-md-paint-fg` set the css `color` in the element
- `swap-md-paint-bg` set the css `background-color` in the element
- `swap-md-paint-bg` set the css `fill` in the element

If you use the `-svg` directive you will also need to set

```
md-icon {
  fill:inherit;
}
```

( Or a more specific selector ) to apply the colors to your svg based icon-buttons

### Fork me on github !

> You can fork me on github: https://github.com/rbecheras/swap-md-paint